# Can't grant CREATE LOGIN securable in SQL Server 2016 SP2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to grant create login permissions to a user using the following code:

```
GRANT CREATE LOGIN TO [loginname];
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'.

This command has worked in SQL Server 2022, but not in SQL Server 2016. I cannot find any documentation saying this was introduced at a later point in time. Does the "Create" aspect of this securable simply not exist in this version?

What I am trying to do is give a user the ability to create new logins and alter the logins they have created, without having access to existing logins.

Comment: What prior version? This didn't work in [2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/CfShZY3A) and I don't recall it being a thing in 2012 (or 2008). The [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) you want is `ALTER ANY LOGIN`.

Comment: @ThomA not a prior version, a future version: 2022. I do not want to give the user permissions to alter any existing logins.

Comment: Looks like the syntax was added in [2022](https://dbfiddle.uk/sYZzoJ88) (as it errors in [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/HeSlynFL)). There is, however, no documentation to say it was added that I can see.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no, I cannot, I have just tried it and it worked on 2022. Is there no way to only allow a user to create and edit new logins without giving them access to all of them?

Comment: Seems it's [not documented yet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), but it's [mentioned here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/new-granular-permissions-for-sql-server-2022-and-azure-sql-to/ba-p/3607507). Anyway, no, there's no way to make that statement work on older versions.

Comment: Found it, @AaronBertrand , but yuck... It's under "Access Control: Permissions" in [What's new in 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022), which then links to *blog post* about [granular permissions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/new-granular-permissions-for-sql-server-2022-and-azure-sql-to/ba-p/3607507)... Not sure why they never got into the documentation

Comment: FWIW- I just submitted a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/9270) against the docs to add this. We'll see how it goes!